# Will Profile Invalid Cause Users To Have To Re-Download App

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, onesignal

I tried using One Signals provisioinator app https://onesignal.com/provisionator today to re-new a Push Certificate, but now when I check in my Apple account my provisioning profile has a status of invalid.

The app is also not in the app store which means changes to certificates and profiles mean the user has to re-download the app. From testing uninstall/reinstall of the app everything appears to be working at the moment.

I think the reason the profile status has been set to invalid is that the identifier that was used to create the certificate is also used by the now invalid profile.

Does anyone have any experience of this and if so is there any chance that this change will force the users to download the app at a later stage?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't affect anything. If your push certificate expires only push notifications will not work. If your account expires even the app will be there on store. You will have some grace period to renew the account but users will be able to download the app. If the app is not in the store then what are you worrying about?